# Load configuration class before BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor

Tags: spring, spring-boot

configuration B below is using BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor to dynamically register some spring beans. However I need to access Configuration class A which is autowired inside B. A always ends up being Null which is due to the fact for BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor - "All regular bean definitions will have been loaded, but no beans will have been instantiated yet"

Is there anyway i can force the configuration loading so that A is instaniated before the Configuration class B so that applicationsProperties is not always null?

A

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "ie.test.appname.applications")
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@RefreshScope
@Data
public class ApplicationProperties {

    private List<Application> applications = new ArrayList<>();

}
```

B

```
      @Configuration
        @Import({ ApplicationProperties.class})
        @Log4j
        public class ConfigurationManager {

            @Autowired
            private ApplicationProperties applicationProperties;

@Bean
    public BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor beanPostProcessor(final ConfigurableEnvironment environment) {
        return new BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor() {
            public void postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory arg0) throws BeansException {
            }

            public void postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(BeanDefinitionRegistry beanRegistry) throws BeansException {
                doSomething();
            }
        };
    }


        private void doSomething() {
        List<Application> storeNamesList = applicationProperties.getApplications(); // null pointer
           }
```

Main with component scan

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
@EnableScheduling
@EnableAsync
@ComponentScan("ie.test.appname")
public class MyApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyApplication .class, args);
    }

}
```

Comment: @DependsOn https://www.baeldung.com/spring-depends-on

Comment: I tried this, didn't work. Are you sure this works for classes dynamically creating beans using BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor